# Does sharding an EC2 EBS volume yield performance gains?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sharding, amazon-ebs

I'm considering using EBS for a very large collection of maildirs. Lots of little files spread over lots of directories. Would sharding my EBS storage into multiple smaller containers yield performance gains in reading/writing versus one large EBS volume?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can explain what exactly you mean by sharding. Otherwise, as performance of EBS is concerned, there are a few drawbacks:

- It's network-bound (e.g. on a smaller instance, where more instances share one host, network performance is sub-stellar).
- It's multi-tenant (again, multiple people on the host affect EBS)
- Its performance varies (performance is never stable)
- **It's not SAN!**

To mitigate some of these issues, a lot of people suggest to create a raid from multiple EBS volumes, I suggest the following articles:

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/08/06/ec2ebs-single-and-raid-volumes-io-bencmark/
- http://orion.heroku.com/past/2009/7/29/io_performance_on_ebs/

Bottomline, for a maildir, I'd probably look into *real hardware*. It doesn't sound like that you need to scale up/down from one minute to another. I'd probably get a setup in place and if necessary use a cloud-solution in addition to temporarily handle spikes (before you get more hardware in place).

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'll read those articles - thank you. What I mean by "sharding" is dividing my maildir corpus in, say, 4 relatively equal parts based on some round robin metric. Then I store all 4 on separate EBS volumes. Let's say my total mail delivery I/O is 10MBps. If I have a single EBS volume, that EBS volume has to keep up with a 10MBps write load. If I have 4 volumes, each has to keep up with (approx.) 2.5MBps write load. My question was: would I be able to keep a higher average write throughput spreading my writes across >1 EBS volumes than I would a single EBS volume.

Comment: I'm guessing that distributing the load like that [c,sh]ould work. I'm not sure how you plan to handle growth in the future though. E.g. different users would make each _shard_ grow in a different way. Not sure if it's always evenly distributed.

Comment: I would suggest using a software RAID.  The bad thing about sharding is that you always have to reschard at some point in time.  That's a major PITA unless your solution supports automatic resharding (e.g. as does MongoDB).

Comment: @j00bz I agree with Till here that this will not distribute evenly. I would not suggest trying to scale like that. In practice you will have some shards experiencing a lot more write load than others in seemingly unpredictable ways.